# User questions by-votes sort order, for same-vote-count questions, is not as it should be

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I have (at least) 2 questions with the same number of votes. One of them (call it Q1) has more views, and more 'favorite' marks, than the other (Q2) - but Q1 is older than Q2. When I choose a 'by votes' display of my question, I expect (*) the sort criteria order to be something like:

votes, favorite marks, views, date, [other stuff]

instead it's

votes, date, [other stuff]

I believe this should not be the case (although, at first I was just wondering whether there was some other rationale I was missing), so - bug report.

**Note:** Why do I have this expectation? Well, the votes sort order is a sorting by a measure of significance, and views and favorite marks are more related to significance than a question's date.

Comment: Why did you expect the criteria to be that?  Is there some documentation that suggests that is the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: So your question is more about changing the current behavior because you think it is inadequate, rather than wondering if it is the intended behavior.  If it wasn't the intended behavior, then it would be a bug.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Ok.

Answer (score 1):

The questions in that view have a single sorting parameter (votes).

Please open a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) if you would like us to implement a "significance" sort so the community can discuss.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe that what you say is true, as AFAICT, items with the same vote count are sorted by date, not just listed arbitrarily. So I do believe this is a bug/misfeature. Please remove the 'bydesign' tag.